# Gazebo "Inserting Models Plugin" loading error, fail to load plugin

Tags: gazebo-plugin, gazebo-1.5

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,
I am new to Gazebo and learning it as i have to do my Final Year Project in it.
I am following the tutorials from the official site of gazebo and now i am stuck at [Inserting Models Plugin.](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.5/plugins/factory)

When at the end i run server it shows error.

> salmaan@ubuntu:~$ gzserver ~/gazebo_plugin_tutorial/factory.sdf
> Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.8.6
> Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
> Released under the Apache 2 License.
> http://gazebosim.org

> Warning [parser.cc:361] Converting a deprecated SDF source[/home/salmaan/gazebo_plugin_tutorial/factory.sdf].
> Warning [Converter.cc:58]   Version[1.3] to Version[1.4]
> Please use the gzsdf tool to update your SDF files.
> $ gzsdf convert [sdf_file]
> Msg Waiting for master
> Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
> Msg Publicized address: 192.168.1.6

> Error [Plugin.hh:126] Failed to load plugin libfactory.so: libfactory.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I discovered that the directory is **build/libfactory.so**, i changed the directory in the world file but still it gives me the same error. :/

NOTE: I am making the files and folders on my home directory, not in gazebo directory. But previous 2 examples of plugins worked fine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3476/gazebo-%22inserting-models-plugin%22-loading-error,-fail-to-load-plugin./) by [SalmaanAhmed](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/394/salmaanahmed/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 17 on 2013-07-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

you have to set up the `GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH` to your plugin file:

```
export GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH=<path_to_your_lib>/:${GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH}
```

you should add this line to your ~/.bashrc file, and then source it.

Another thing, you should fix the sdf since it is an older version, you could run this tool for that:

```
$ gzsdf convert <path_to_sdf>/factory.sdf
```

Cheers,
Andrei

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2013-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SalmaanAhmed](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/394/salmaanahmed/) on 2013-07-08**:
i copied

> export GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=$HOME/gazebo_plugin_tutorial/models:$GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH
> at end of the .bashrc file...
> But it gives me the same error ....
> Dont know why ???

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-07-08**:
What is the exact path of your plugin?

**Comment by [SalmaanAhmed](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/394/salmaanahmed/) on 2013-07-09**:
it is /home/salmaan/gazebo_plugin_tutorial/factory.cc

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-07-09**:
export `GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH` as well, /lib

**Comment by [SalmaanAhmed](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/394/salmaanahmed/) on 2013-07-09**:
It worked. Thanks, You rock :)